# Nodejs Mysql Only Inserting one item

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi i am trying to build an odd display website for soccer matches
Im trying to get data from betfair which works fine then insert it to my database
Problem is that the function is only inserting the first item, what should i do?

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const appendFile = util.promisify(fs.appendFile);
const async = require("async");

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'betfair'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

var url = 'https://www.betfair.com/sport/football';

var customHeaderRequest = request.defaults({
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'}
})

customHeaderRequest.get(url, async function(err, resp, body){
  try {
    let $ = cheerio.load(body);
    let links = $('.section-list .section:nth-child(2) .event-list li').toArray();
    for (let link of links) {

        const id = $(link).find('.event-information .avb-col-markets a:nth-child(1)').attr('href');
        const idx = id.replace('/sport/football/event?eventId=', '');

        const home = $(link).find('.event-information div:nth-child(3) div a div span.team-name:nth-child(1)').text().trim();
        const away = $(link).find('.event-information div:nth-child(3) div a div span.team-name:nth-child(2)').text().trim();

        const x1 = $(link).find('.event-information .avb-col-markets .market-3-runners .runner-list li:nth-child(1) a .ui-runner-price').text().trim();
        const x = $(link).find('.event-information .avb-col-markets .market-3-runners .runner-list li:nth-child(2) a .ui-runner-price').text().trim();
        const x2 = $(link).find('.event-information .avb-col-markets .market-3-runners .runner-list li:nth-child(3) a .ui-runner-price').text().trim();

        const over = $(link).find('.event-information .avb-col-markets .market-2-runners .runner-list li:nth-child(1) a .ui-runner-price').text().trim();
        const under = $(link).find('.event-information .avb-col-markets .market-2-runners .runner-list li:nth-child(2) a .ui-runner-price').text().trim();
        if (home && away) {

          connection.query("INSERT INTO bf (id, home, away, x1, x, x2, over, under) VALUES ('"+idx+"', '"+home+"', '"+away+"', '"+x1+"', '"+x+"', '"+x2+"', '"+over+"', '"+under+"')", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
          });
        }
    }
  } catch(e) {
  }
});
```

I have tried plenty of thinks but im not that good in nodejs and i am looking for your help
Thanks

Comment: You need to log the errors - it should help you find the issue. change the:

`} catch(e) {
}`

to

`} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}`

Comment: @yeya dont know why but the id.replace throws error after inserting first item. I removed it and works like a charm now thank you

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what the error is but I guess you don't really need the id so removing it will be OK.

P.S. Your code has many more issues, the most important one is the sql query.

You should use [knex](https://knexjs.org/) or at least change it to:

`INSERT INTO bf (home, away, x1, x, x2, over, under) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
 [home, away, x1, x, x2, over, under], function (err, result) {`

[Source](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)